# Elastic search AND/BOOL condition + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I want to pass AND condtion in elastic search query. if 'manuf_id' and 'network_id' is > 0 but this is not working properly.

```
 "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                              "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => $query
                          ]
                     ],

                  ]
               ]
            ]

if ($manufacture > 0 && $network > 0) {
            $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = [
            'term' => ['manuf_id' => $manufacture],
            'term' => ['network_id' => $network],
            ];
        }
```

Any help or reference would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each `term` constraint separately:

```
if ($manufacture > 0 && $network > 0) {
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = [
        'term' => ['manuf_id' => $manufacture]
    ];
    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = [
        'term' => ['network_id' => $network]
    ];
}
```